# Is there a Python library for connecting to a PostgreSQL 8.4 server using certificate authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, postgresql, certificate

We are in the process of upgrading from PostgreSQL 8.3 to PostgreSQL 8.4, in a large part so that we can start using [certificate-based authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-CERT).

We have some Python 2.x code that accesses the database that uses [PyGreSQL](http://www.pygresql.org/). Is there a way to get it or any other Python library to use a cert to access PostgreSQL?

Looking through the PyGreSQL source, I didn't see a way to supply a certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psycopg2 is based on libpq, so it should work there. I don't think there's a specific interface for it, so you'll have to use the environment variables (see the libpq documentation) to control it, but it should work. (disclaimer: I haven't actually tried it, but anything on top of libpq *should* work)

Comment: Looks like PyGreSQL is based on libpq as well, and sure enough works fine if I put the certificates in the default locations and pass no username nor password.